# Remove everything between 2 chars using sed

Tags: script, sed

I am trying to remove a string from and including one char, '_' up to but not including another char, ':'. Everything is on the same line.

I have files with different names and numbers, that contain for example:

```
some_name_123:456(other_name_123:456,some_word_567:765, and so on...
```

I am trying to remove the `_123`, which is a different pattern in each file, so I end up with:

```
some_name:456(other_name:456,some_word:765,
```

However, I can only seem to remove everything from the first `_` to the `:` which gives `some_:456` which isn't what I want.  Below is what I have so far. Can anybody help?

```
sed -e 's/\(+\).*\(@\)/\1\2/'
```

This gives what I want on the first occurrence, but not the rest of the occurrences:

```
sed 's/_[^_]\+:/:/'
```

Comment: (1) You say “I am trying to remove everything between 2 chars.” What two characters? ``_``  and  `:`? Do you want to remove `_` and all following characters *up to **but not including*** `:`? (This is not a common meaning of “between”.) (2) It’s very confusing when you say “I am trying to remove the `_123`” and then show `three_567:765` changing to `three:765` (i.e., removing the  `_567`). (3) If you want to remove everything from `_` to `:` (which you finally say in *the **last** paragraph)* why are you using `+`  and  `@` in your `sed` command? (3a) Do you understand what `\1` and `\2` mean?

Comment: I have tried to make it more clear. So from and including the '_' and up to but not including the ':'. What you are saying is confusing is because it is what I ended up with but not what I want. I dont want to remove any of the words.

Comment: The OP obviously found [How to remove everything between two characters with SED?](https://superuser.com/questions/1397313/how-to-remove-everything-between-two-characters-with-sed); the `sed -e 's/\(+\).*\(@\)/\1\2/'` command is copied verbatim from there, even though it uses the "two characters" from *that* question, not from *this* one. The OP did so little research that they didn't bother to figure out what that command was doing.  And, even after I asked why they were using `+`  and  `@` in their `sed` command, they declined to admit that they were plagiarizing an old question.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is an unclear PLAGIARIZED duplicate — see comments.

Answer (score 1):

`echo "some_name_123:456" | sed 's/\(.*\)_.*:\(.*\)/\1:\2/g'`

gives

`some_name:456`

is it that what you want?

Comment: Some_name_123:456 is an example. the words and numbers are all different

Comment: @cats123 Have you tried the `sed` command using some other name and number?

Comment: there are thousands of different numbers so I cant use a specific number

Comment: @cats123 you don't have to. The `sed` part will work for different texts in the `echo` part. The `echo` part is just there to give a complete, working example.

Comment: even though every name and number combination is different? When i remove the echo part it doesnt work